# Add satellite layer from google/bing/other

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, satellite

I am using openlayers3 and I have to set a satellite layer from google,bing or other provider.

How can I do this?

At the moment I have this code:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
                layer: 'osm'
            })
        });
map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [raster,vector],
            view: new ol.View({
              center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.2589271, 43.8004469]),
              zoom: 15
            })
        });
```

I am using:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var layerBing = new ol.layer.Tile({
    preload: Infinity,
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
      key: 'Your Key',
      imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels'
    })
  });
```

Get your key at http://www.bingmapsportal.com/